# Display route without any action

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In Angular2 is it possible to **display just route** in the browser **but don't use any Angular2 components**? Some kind of ignore in `RouterModule.forRoot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. You have to pass component, module or redirect to other path, like the error says:

Invalid configuration of route 'some-route': one of the following must be provided (component or redirectTo or children or loadChildren)

Comment: Is it possible to not provide any template for new component and work with existing DOM elements?

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure what are you trying to say. You want to work with existing DOM elements which are where if they are not in the template?

Comment: I'm trying to open modal window by changing URL in browser. Having troubles with it..

Comment: You can leave the template empty and then in constructor inject ActivatedRoute, get the parameters from it and then open modal. I guess, you are using some of the angular 2 way modals.

Comment: If I put '' as a template it inserts empty into page.. Can I ask angular2 to not insert this?

Comment: You can put for the example <div></div> and solve the problem :)

Comment: Yeah.. :) Buut let's imagine that I have some content on the page already here.. and I don't want to miss this content))

Comment: I understand the problem. I don't have an answer.  I need to think about it. :)